# Does the Laver real determine the generic filter?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let us concern the Laver forcing $ \mathbb{L} $.

Let $ G $ be $ \mathbb{L} $-generic over a c.t.m. $ M $ for ZFC. Let
$$
x_G := \bigcup \{ \operatorname{stem}(p) : p \in G \}
$$
be the Laver real determined by $ G $.

Now, Jech ("Set Theory", 3rd edition, p.565) claims
$$
G = \{ p \in \mathbb{L}^M : \forall n < \omega \ x_G \mathord{\upharpoonright} n \in p \} =: F.
$$

The inclusion $ G \subseteq F $ clearly holds.

But how can one show $ F \subseteq G $?

---

Is $ F $ even a filter?

For example, imagine the following situation:

- $ x_G(n) = 0 $ for all $ n < \omega $,
- there are $ p, q \in \mathbb{L}^M $ such that
- $ \operatorname{stem}(p) = \operatorname{stem}(q) = \emptyset $,
- at each node of $ p $ the successors are exactly $ 0, 2, 4, 6, \ldots $,
- at each node of $ q $ the successors are exactly $ 0, 1, 3, 5, \ldots $.

Then $ p, q \in F $, but $ p \perp q $ because $ p \cap q = \{ x_G \mathord{\upharpoonright} n : n < \omega \} $ does not contain any Laver tree.

What am I missing?

Comment: Clearly if you had such $p,q\in V$ then $x_G\in V$. Therefore no such $p$ and $q$ exist in the ground model.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not exactly understand your argument.

Comment: Show that $x_G\notin V$ as a first step. Then when trying to prove that $F$ is a filter, you can use that fact to conclude that if $p,q\in F$ but there is no $r\in F$ such that $r\subseteq p\cap q$, then you can define $x_G$ in $V$ itself. But that's a contradiction.

Comment: If $ M $ is a c.t.m. for a suitable finite fragment of ZFC, then $ \mathbb{L} \in M $, so $ \mathbb{L} \subseteq M $. So, if there are $ p, q \in F \subseteq M $ with $ \bigcup (p \cap q) = x_G $ (as above), then clearly $ x_G \in M $. Of course, $ G \notin M $ as $ \mathbb{L} $ is separative. But how does $ x_G \in M $ imply $ G \in M $ without the questioned equality?

Comment: Ok, I will try that. (You can forget my second comment.) Thanks again!

Comment: The Laver real $ x_G $ eventually dominates all ground model reals, so $ x_G \notin M $.

Is there a more direct proof of $ x_G \notin M $?

Comment: And I do not see how that definition of $ x_G $ in the ground model works under the assumption you stated.

Comment: The usual density argument. Given $f\colon\omega\to\omega$ in $V$, every condition $p$ can be extended by removing the node above the stem which agrees with $f$, so the stronger condition disagrees with $f$. Therefore $x_G\neq f$ for all $f\in V$.

Comment: I was a blockhead concerning that density argument. The more puzzling question remains. Is it as simple as the other one? Maybe you can give me another hint or I just have to think harder and longer.

Comment: Well, the second argument is slightly more difficult. But I am sure that it's essentially down to that idea. I don't have too much time to think about it in full, but I'll try to sneak some thought between here and there.

Comment: Try to prove the following: If $p$ and $q$ are Laver trees but $p \cap q$ isn't then there is a real (in M) that is not dominated by any real in $[p] \cap [q] = [p \cap q]$. Now use your fact that the Laver real dominates every ground model real.

Comment: While you're learning Laver forcing, here's a nice and hard application to think about: Let $f:\omega^{\omega} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be any continuous function. Show that there is a Laver tree $T \subseteq \omega^{< \omega}$ such that $f \upharpoonright [T]$ is either one-one or constant.

Comment: @hot_queen Thanks for your comment. I guess my problem is how to characterize "there is no Laver tree $ r \subseteq p \cap q $". I totally don't get the idea how to construct the ground model real in that situation. Maybe you can give me another hint?

Comment: Dear justus, I take back my unjustified claim and I am thinking about your question. I will post again soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma.**

Let $ p \in \mathbb{L} $ and suppose $ q \subseteq \omega^{< \omega} $ is a tree that does not contain any Laver tree.

Then there is a Laver tree $ r \in \mathbb{L} $ such that $ [r] \subseteq [p] \setminus [q] $.

*Proof.* Note $ [p] \setminus [q] \neq \emptyset $. Otherwise $ [p] \subseteq [q] $, so
$$ p = \{ x \mathord{\upharpoonright} n : x \in [p] \land n < \omega \} \subseteq \{ x \mathord{\upharpoonright} n : x \in [q] \land n < \omega \} \subseteq q, $$
a contradiction.

Let $ x \in [p] \setminus [q] $. Then there is some $ n < \omega $ such that $ x \mathord{\upharpoonright} n \notin [q] $. Now,
$$ r := \{ s \in p : s \subseteq x \mathord{\upharpoonright} n \lor s \supseteq x \mathord{\upharpoonright} n \} $$
is as wished.

*QED.*

---

**Proof of $ F \subseteq G $.** (Based on hot_queen's answer and comments.)

Assume $ G \subsetneq F $. Then we find $ q \in F \setminus G $ and $ p \in G $ such that $ p \perp q $, i.e. $ \forall r \in \mathbb{L}^M \ r \nsubseteq p \cap q $.

Now
$$
D_q := \{ r \in \mathbb{L}^M : ([r] \cap [q] = \emptyset)^M \} \in M
$$
is dense below $ p $. To see this, fix $ p' \leq p $. Then $ p' \perp q $, so $ q' := p' \cap q $ does not contain any Laver tree. We use the above Lemma (within $ M $) to find $ r \leq p' $ with
$$
\Bigl( [r] \subseteq [p'] \setminus [q'] = [p'] \setminus ([p'] \cap [q]) = [p'] \setminus [q] \Bigr)^M,
$$
so $ ([r] \cap [q] = \emptyset)^M $ and hence $ r \in D_q $.

Now, fix $ r \in G \cap D_q $. Then $ ([r \cap q] = [r] \cap [q] = \emptyset)^M $, i.e.
$$
({\supsetneq} \text{ is well-founded on the tree } r \cap q)^M.
$$
But the notion of well-foundation is absolute, so $ (x_G \in [r \cap q] = \emptyset)^{M[G]} $ - a contradiction.

*QED.*

Comment: This answer is based on hot_queen's answer and comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Can you show (or maybe disprove this): If $T$ is Laver tree and $T'$ is a tree which doesn't contain a Laver tree then $[T] \backslash [T']$ contains the set of branches through a Laver tree?

Ok. Now using a density argument show the following: If $p \in G$, then for every Laver tree $q$, if $p, q$ are incompatible then there is some $p_1 \leq p$, $p_1 \in G$ and $[p_1] \cap [q] = \phi$. It follows that if $x_G \in [q]$, then $q \in G$ - Otherwise, for some $p \in G$, $p, q$ are incompatible, hence for some $p_1 \leq p$, $p_1 \in G$ and $[p_1] \cap [q] = \phi$ which is impossible because $x_G \in [p_1] \cap [q]$.

Let me also add a few remarks about how the situation is analogous to random forcing (and many other forcings): In the random poset $P$, conditions are compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ of positive measure and for $p, q \in P$, we write $p \leq q$ iff $p \subseteq q$. If $G$ is $P$-generic over the ground model then there is a unique real $r_G$ which is a member of every set in $G$. You can then show that $G$ is the set of all positive measure compact sets coded in the ground model which contain $r_G$. Along the way, you'll also show that there is no measure zero Borel set coded in the ground model which contains $r_G$; this is also sufficient for $r_G$ to be random generic. The analogue of this for Laver forcing is that the Laver real cannot be a branch of any tree in the ground model which does not contain a Laver tree. Maybe you can now show that Laver reals are precisely the reals which do not form a branch of a small tree coded in the ground model where small means that it does not contain a Laver tree.

Comment: Thanks again. I proved your claim. (See the edit.) But how do you use that lemma to solve my original problem?

Comment: Again, thanks for your answer. But $ p_1 \cap q = \emptyset $ cannot be true. Do you mean $ [p_1] \cap [q] = \emptyset $ (see my latest edit above) or maybe $ \operatorname{Split}(p_1) \cap \operatorname{Split}(q) = \emptyset $?

Comment: Yes, I edited. Does this make sense now?

Comment: Please have a look at my question again. I cannot complete the proof with your idea! :-(

Comment: $[r] \cap [q]$ is a closed set coded in $M$. Show that if it is non empty in $M[G]$, then it is also non empty in $M$.

Comment: You should also read about well founded subtrees of $\omega^{<\omega}$ (these are trees for which have no infinite branch) if you haven't heard about them. The above follows from the fact that being well founded is absolute between transitive models of ZFC.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This finally solves my question. (Just in case, you may proofread my proof (see **Edit #3 & #4** above).)